# How do I configure a command line email client to send and receive email from the command line in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, email, mailutils

I have been exploring command line email clients for a while now and it is not clear to me which would be the most standard tool and set-up.

I want to send emails from the command line without opening a specific GUI application like Mutt, and I also would like to save my email inbox on my filesystem, search through it for a list of particular emails, and access those emails for reading in some way.

I don't know which command line email program is most standard for this need, maybe mailutils or s-nail, and what a simple Gmail configuration for the tool would be. Different tools seem to use different configuration files and I don't yet know if they share a universal syntax or not.

I haven't found Googling or reading very long mail program documentations to be particularly helpful. A lot of Google searches return what seem to be keyword mismatches.

Comment: a set of command examples is set out [here](https://blog.edmdesigner.com/send-email-from-linux-command-line/)